# Place left fixed positioned div to the bottom of the page without javascript on screen size change

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

This is the html for the social sharing links.

```
'<div id="social_share">
   <ul>
    <li id="facebook">
     <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="'. plugins_url( '/32x32/facebook35x35.png' , __FILE__ ) .'" /></a>
    </li>
    <li id="twitter">
     <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="'. plugins_url( '/32x32/twitter35x35.png' , __FILE__ ).'" /></a>
    </li>
    <li id="gplus">
     <a href="http://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="'.plugins_url( '/32x32/googleplus35x35.png' , __FILE__ ).'" /></a>
    </li>
    <li id="youtube">
     <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img src="'.plugins_url('/32x32/youtube35x35.png', __FILE__).'" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>'
```

This is the css which make it float to the right of the page

```
/*GLOBAL STYLES*/
#facebook, #twitter, #gplus, #youtube{
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*MEDIA QUERIES*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
#social_share{
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    z-index: 10;
    right:10px;
    top:350px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#social_share{
    /*z-index: 10;*/
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#facebook, #twitter, #gplus, #youtube{
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

How should I position it at the bottom of the page when the screen size reduces to less than 980px. The

```
bottom: 0;
```

but it doesn't work. Please note: I don't want it to stick to the bottom of the screen. I want it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

here is the trick which I use most of the times for footer, this will stick to the bottom only if content is less than window height.

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/